# Create descending ranks for a set of columns using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How do you use `dplyr` to create ranks for each column based on descending values for multiple columns?
The code below seemingly does not consider the `desc` parameter in the `arrange_at`

```
rank_f <- function(ds, cols, fs){
          ds %>%arrange_at(desc(vars(!!!cols)))%>%
            mutate_at(vars(!!!cols), funs(!!!fs))
        }


USArrests %>%tibble::rownames_to_column()%>%
     rank_f(quos((Murder:Rape)),quos(min_rank))->ranked


head(USArrests) 
#              Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
# Alabama      13.2     236       58 21.2
# Alaska       10.0     263       48 44.5
# Arizona       8.1     294       80 31.0
# Arkansas      8.8     190       50 19.5
# California    9.0     276       91 40.6
# Colorado      7.9     204       78 38.7

head(ranked)
#        rowname Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
# 1    Alabama     44      35       16   29
# 2     Alaska     35      43        7   49
# 3    Arizona     29      47       39   43
# 4   Arkansas     31      31        9   24
# 5 California     32      44       50   48
# 6   Colorado     28      33       38   47
```

The higher the rate, the lower the rank should be, which is not the case.

Comment: It is not clear what the expected output might be.  Can you show the expected output for first few rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to place this inside the `funs`

```
out1 <- USArrests %>%
           tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
           arrange_at(vars(Murder:Rape), funs(desc))
```

Checking with applying `desc` on each column

```
out2 <-  USArrests %>% 
             tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
             arrange(desc(Murder), desc(Assault), desc(UrbanPop), desc(Rape))
identical(out1, out2)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Based on the above, we can make changes in the `rank_f`

```
out3 <-  out2 %>%
             mutate_at(vars(Murder:Rape), min_rank) 
rank_f <- function(ds, cols, fs){
          ds %>%
               arrange_at(vars(!!!cols), funs(desc))%>%
               mutate_at(vars(!!!cols), funs(!!!fs))
        }
out4 <- USArrests %>%
             tibble::rownames_to_column()%>%
             rank_f(quos((Murder:Rape)),quos(min_rank))

identical(out3, out4)
#[1] TRUE
```

#### Update

Based on the comments from OP, we don't need to do any `arrange`, we can directly apply `min_rank` by converting the column values to negative

```
USArrests %>% 
   tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% 
   mutate_at(vars(Murder:Rape), funs(min_rank(-.)))
```

Comment: adding `%>%arrange(rowname)` I still get the rank in ascending order      `rowname Murder Assault UrbanPop Rape
1    Alabama     44      35       16   29
2     Alaska     35      43        7   49
3    Arizona     29      47       39   43
4   Arkansas     31      31        9   24
5 California     32      44       50   48
6   Colorado     28      33       38   47`

Comment: @Lod Please check the `identical` output

Comment: @Lod I have showed both without using the `quos` and by applying `desc` on each column spearately and it gives the same output.  May be your logic is not clear

Comment: might be I misunderstand how the `_at` works. What I am looking for is a new data frame with for each column the rank of each observation for that column. With the rank based on the descending value so higher value, lower rank. So, in my example the rank for Murder for Alabama definitely should be lower than for Alaska.

Comment: @Lod Do you need `USArrests %>% tibble::rownames_to_column() %>% mutate_at(vars(Murder:Rape), funs(min_rank(-.))) %>% head`

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for: to get the (-.) into the function

Comment: @Lod  I think it may be better to create the whole flow as a function instead of implementing it piecewise

Comment: what would you suggest?